# Flask and Sendgrid - 401 error on localhost

Tags: python, flask, localhost, sendgrid

I am trying to use Sendgrid's Python API to handle transactional emails in my Flask app.

When I fire up the localhost server, I am getting a 401 error when I complete the invite form and attempt to connect with the sendgrid API and I can't understand why.

I import my sendgrid API key from a sendgrid.env file.

**The app's init:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sendgrid
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://unible:test@localhost/unible'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '\xea5\x1b.S3ME\x86\x8bP/\x86T\xca\x8f\xf4S\xe2h\x9c\xe5\xc6h'
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['DAYS_TIL_INVITES_EXPIRE'] = 28

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
sendgrid = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))

import unible.routes
```

**The routing file:**

Then import the sendgrid object into my routes file to create and send mail.

```
from unible import app, sendgrid
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, flash
from unible.models.invite import Invite
from .forms.InviteForm import InviteForm
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *
import urllib

@app.route('/account/invites/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new_invites():
    form = InviteForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('invite_form.html', form=form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        invite_from = 1 # for testing only, will be replaced by session user id
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            invite_for = form.email.data.lower()
            invite = Invite(invite_from, invite_for)

            from_email = Email("test@example.com")
            subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid Python Library!"
            to_email = Email("test@example.com")
            content = Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!")
            msg = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

            try:
                response = sendgrid.client.mail.send.post(request_body=msg.get())
                print(response.status_code)
                print(response.body)
                print(response.headers)
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
                print(e.read())
            flash('An invite email was sent to %s' % invite_for)
            return redirect(url_for('new_invites'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('new_invites'))
```

The error I get back is this:

```
b'{"errors":[{"message":"The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked","field":null,"help":null}]}'
```

However when I run the same [sample code from here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#with-mail-helper-class) outside of a server it runs fine and sends?

Comment: So it turns out after a bit of printing, that the API wasn't loading and was passing `None` hence a 401.  For now I've included it as a variable on app.config but will need to work out how assign it from the environment.

Comment: So it is also because of my shell set up.  I use zsh not bash and so how and where environment variables are stored / called from differs.

Comment: This helped: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-set-environment-variables-in-zsh